# Taxonomy terms with edit/filter link in wp-admin, in the list of custom posts

Tags: custom-post-types, taxonomy, filters, links

I'm using [get_the_term_list](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_the_term_list) and [manage_posts_custom_column](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/manage_posts_custom_column) to display the terms of a custom taxonomy in the list of custom posts, in the WordPress Admin.

```
add_action( 'manage_mycustompost_posts_custom_column' , 'custom_mycustompost_column', 10, 2 );

function custom_mycustompost_column( $column, $post_id ) {
  switch ( $column ) {
    case 'category_names':
        echo get_the_term_list( $post_id , 'mycustomcategory' , '' , ',' , '' );
        break;
  }
}
```

However, for each taxonomy term, I get a link to the public page that shows posts for that term:
http://www.myblog.com/mycustomcategory/test/

I would like to get a link that filters the list in the WordPress Admin. I would like a link like:
http://www.myblog.com/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=post&category_name=news

The type of link I get in the Posts list, for tags or categories of the default WordPress posts.

Is there a WordPress function that does that?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't have it wrapped inside a function you can use, but the following will work:

```
$taxonomy = 'my-taxonomy';
$taxonomy_object = get_taxonomy( $taxonomy );
$object_type = get_post_type($post_id);

if ( $terms = get_the_terms( $post_id, $taxonomy ) ) {
      $out = array();
      foreach ( $terms as $t ) {
           $posts_in_term_qv = array();
           $posts_in_term_qv['post_type'] = $object_type;

           if ( $taxonomy_object->query_var ) {
                 $posts_in_term_qv[ $taxonomy_object->query_var ] = $t->slug;
           } else {
                 $posts_in_term_qv['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy;
                 $posts_in_term_qv['term'] = $t->slug;
           }

           $out[] = sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
                    esc_url( add_query_arg( $posts_in_term_qv, 'edit.php' ) ),
                    esc_html( sanitize_term_field( 'name', $t->name, $t->term_id, $taxonomy, 'display' ) )
                 );
        }

      /* translators: used between list items, there is a space after the comma */
       echo join( __( ', ' ), $out );
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I was hoping for an easier, built-in way, especially as WordPress uses this functionality for the default posts list...

Comment: Nope :). Actually that was pretty much lifted out of WP 3.5 core (see this trac ticket: http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21240 )